# Flex SQLite Local database encryption - SimpleEncryptionKeyGenerator.as

Tags: database, apache-flex, sqlite, encryption, air

I'm trying to use the Simple Encryption Key Generator Class found here - http://www.dehats.com/drupal/?q=node/62

Everything seems to working properly except the hash encryption key that is returned is the same string every time (as mentioned in the the comments of the link above). I haven't  been able to fix the issue or locate an updated version of this class and was hoping someone might know of a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SHA Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) would throw the different hash value each time for different text,
the `mx.utils.SHA256` has been computed based on this
[Standard](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips180-2/fips180-2.pdf).

You Can Find out the Cryptography algorithms in the Following [Tour de Flex](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-archive/flex/tourdeflex/web/#illustIndex=1;sampleId=50103;docIndex=0) Link under the
**Other Components -> Ecrypt -> AS3 cryptography**. where you can find the SHA256 algorithm under the HASH tab.

I think It might Help You.